# Issue while displaying image inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have an activity which has ViewPager to see multiple images. Each fragment has a TextView and an ImageView inside RelativeLayout. I tried to put a RelativeLayout inside a ScrollView so that it supports Scrolling. However when i do it, my image is shrunk and doesn't occupy entire width of screen. Can someone please highlight what might be causing this issue. Here is my activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/ad_view"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:context=".activities.SliderImageActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/ad_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
```

Here is my fragment

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:scrollbars="none|vertical">
<LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".activities.SliderImageActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/section_label" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000080" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Here is how i see activity now

[image: Screenshot]

I want to see this image taking complete width (as originally it has that much width) and should come immediately below TextView

Comment: put android:fillViewport="true" in scrollView fragment xml file

Comment: where you want to put your textview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing to add `android:orientation="vertical"` for LinearLayout and 
 `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` for your ImageView

Replace your code Like this

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none|vertical">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        tools:context=".activities.SliderImageActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/section_label" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#000080" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:id="@+id/imageView" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Let me know your result

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `android:scaleType="center"` in your `ImageView`

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:id="@+id/imageView" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use this `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` for your `ImageView`

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@id/img"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```